# Seaborn Jointplot error: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, runtime-error, seaborn

I'm trying to create a JointPlot for the following Customer Data Dataframe. I need the Jointplot to have the Yearly Amount Spent on the Y axis and Time Spent on App on the X axis.

The Dataframe looks like this

[image: Fig 1: Customer Data Dataframe]

I use the following to create the Jointplot, but get the error below.

[image: Fig 2: Seaborn command to create Jointplot of Yearly amout spent to Time spent and error]

I am expecting the following Jointplot (instead of the error) Appreciate your help in resolving this!

[image: Fig 3: Seaborn command should create the following Jointplot instead of above error]

Comment: This is only a warning, not an error. If you do not see the plot it has nothing to do with the warning. Maybe you haven't selected any automatic backend like `%matplotlib inline` or `%matplotlib notebook`?

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you ImportanceOfBeignEarnest for the answer you posted in comment.

This was an oversight - I had forgotten the line %matplotlib inline

Includes at the top are now:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
```

The warning still come ups but the plot appears now.